# Pygame Circle Fill Number of Arguments Passed Error

Tags: python

For some unknown reason,I cannot fill the circle in PyGame.It says to pass 5 arguments,but 6 were given.As far as I can see,I've passed 5.

```
pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, yellow, (750+lead_z, 200), 75, 45,2)
```

And yes,I have defined lead_z,and yellow.
Lead z is 300 and yellow,of course, is the RGB color.

Comment: I count 6 arguments.

Comment: Please list them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I count 6.

```
pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, yellow, (750+lead_z, 200), 75, 0)
```

That would give you a filled circle with radius 75.

Answer (score 2):

I count 6 arguments:

```
1. gameDisplay
2. yellow
3. (750 + lead_z, 200)
4. 75
5. 45
7. 2
```